# CNN prediction not correct

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I experimented with German traffic sign classification using keras. I got 99% val_accuracy when the data set is unbalanced. Then, I checked the F1-score using the classification report:

```
print(classification_report(y_test1, y_pred_bool))

             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       1.00      0.96      0.98        54
          1       0.99      0.99      0.99       618
          2       0.98      1.00      0.99       499
          3       0.98      0.99      0.99       341
          4       1.00      0.98      0.99       472
          5       0.98      1.00      0.99       572
          6       0.99      1.00      0.99       176
          7       1.00      0.98      0.99       176
          8       1.00      1.00      1.00        98
          9       1.00      1.00      1.00       294
         10       0.99      1.00      1.00       313
         11       0.96      0.98      0.97        56
         12       0.99      0.99      0.99       553
         13       0.99      0.96      0.97        95
         14       1.00      1.00      1.00        87
         15       0.98      1.00      0.99       104
         16       0.99      1.00      0.99       133
         17       1.00      0.99      0.99        67
         18       0.98      1.00      0.99       345
         19       1.00      1.00      1.00       151
         20       1.00      1.00      1.00        50
         21       1.00      0.98      0.99       153
         22       0.97      0.99      0.98        73
         23       0.99      0.99      0.99       350
         24       0.99      0.96      0.98       104
         25       1.00      1.00      1.00       217
         26       1.00      1.00      1.00        54
         27       1.00      0.99      0.99       165
         28       0.95      0.98      0.96        93
         29       0.99      1.00      0.99       275
         30       0.98      1.00      0.99        95
         31       1.00      1.00      1.00        58
         32       1.00      0.99      1.00       535
         33       0.98      1.00      0.99        62
         34       0.99      1.00      0.99       497
         35       1.00      0.98      0.99       100
         36       1.00      1.00      1.00        65
         37       0.98      0.98      0.98        49
         38       1.00      0.94      0.97       446
         39       0.98      1.00      0.99        90
         40       0.97      1.00      0.99       368
         41       1.00      0.99      1.00       337
         42       1.00      0.99      1.00       363

   accuracy                           0.99      9803
  macro avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      9803
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      9803
```

Then, I checked the confusion matrix, which is correct.

I saved the model on my disk and loaded it again to predict images from every class with the following code: :

```
model = load_model('/kaggle/working/models-07-0.9904.h5')
pred = model.predict(images1)
print(pred)
y_pred_bool = np.argmax(pred, axis = 1)
print(y_pred_bool)
```

Unfortunately, most of the predictions are wrong and I don't know why. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

It has multi - label classification

I took first 10 images from every label and make the prediction

The corresponding labels are

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42]
```

The y_pred_bool

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
    1,  1,  1, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 23, 23, 23, 23,
   23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 38,
   38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39,
   39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41,
   41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,
    3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,
    5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,
    7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
    9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
   10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13,
   13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15,
   15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16,
   16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18,
   18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20,
   20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,  3, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
   21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
   24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26,
   26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27,
   28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29,
   29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31,
   31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33,
   33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35,
   35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37,
   37, 37, 37, 37, 37])
```

Comment: How do you encode and decode your labels? What kind of classification are you doing, binary or multi-labels? I would try to debug the labeling since your model seems to work pretty well

Comment: What's the output of print(pred) and print(y_pred_bool)?

Comment: You are probably forgetting to preprocess the new images1 file the way you did on the input files. Check the preprocessing section. Check normalization, file reshaping, colors, etc.

Comment: My pre-processing is gray scale image then resize to 32,32 and scaled by 1/255. I pre-processed the test images in the same way I did in the training.

Comment: Its difficult to identify the error from your output. What is the optimizer, loss function you are using? Please post your code along with Dataset Statistics(number of classes, number of records for each class etc). Also how are you saving the model?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving and loading the model and **evaluating on the same dataset, the results must not change** before saving and after loading the model.

**Example:** I have run a simple model and saved using model.save and the did the load with load_model of keras. You can download the pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv dataset from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv) (If not available here, you can download from kaggle and other sources).

**Build, Evaluate and Save the model -**

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
# MLP for Pima Indians Dataset saved to single file
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# load pima indians dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt("/content/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Model Summary
model.summary()

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

# save model and architecture to single file
model.save("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

Output -

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1630: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/nn_impl.py:183: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 12)                108       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 104       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 9         
=================================================================
Total params: 221
Trainable params: 221
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:422: The name tf.global_variables is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.global_variables instead.

accuracy: 75.78%
Saved model to disk
```

**Load and Evaluate the Model -**

```
# load and evaluate a saved model
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import load_model

# load model
model = load_model('model.h5')

# summarize model.
model.summary()

# load dataset
dataset = loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]

# evaluate the model
score = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))
```

Output -

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 12)                108       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 104       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 9         
=================================================================
Total params: 221
Trainable params: 221
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
accuracy: 75.78%
```